# .CAT file in MikeOS

Tags: assembly, operating-system, archive

I'm making a custom OS based on MikeOS. In the MikeOS `.iso`, there is a file called `BOOT.CAT`. If I build a custom version, will I need that file to make my OS bootable? If yes, what's in it and how do I make one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BOOT.CAT` is a usual name for the so-called Boot Catalog. It is a concept from the El Torito specification, which defines how bootable CDs and DVDs are supposed to be formatted. It is required to make a CD/DVD bootable, but other than that, it's not very interesting.

You can use `mkisofs` from [cdrtools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdrtools) to [create a bootable `.iso`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bootdisk-HOWTO/cd-roms.html), which will create the `BOOT.CAT` file for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to use this.